# Google apps script save google spreadsheet to excel version and load it from add-on

Tags: json, xml, excel, google-apps-script, vba

Hi I have an idea about file management between GAS and my BDserver. How so? Well, I'd like to have predesigned spreadsheet and save them somehow in my bd. Then users've installed my add-on can load that predesigned spreadsheet on his/her current spreadsheet. PD: Besides the user could save custom "predesigned spreadsheets" for helping to grow the app. How can I save a spreadsheet (Google Drive Spreadsheet) in my server and later call that "file" and load it in a empty spreadsheet? xml? json? export like excel file .xls??.  I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find helpful information in [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#what_can_apps_script_do) regarding the things that you can do with Google Apps like Docs, Sheets and Forms. You can also find links from the documentation which could help if you've developed a script for Google Sheets and want to share it with the world. App Script lets you publish your script as an add-on so others can install it from the add-on store.

In addition to that, to save your spreadsheet in your own database, you need to connect to it through Apps Script's JDBC service. First, you need to ensure that your database accepts connections from any of Apps Script's IP addresses as detailed in [JDBC - Setup for other databases](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_other_databases).